# java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: {}HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity

Tags: android, http, okhttp

I switched our HTTP library over from Apache to OkHttp3 on my company's Android app.

The okHttp Client is set up in the following manner :

```
mDefaultClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(getSocketTimeOut(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(getSocketTimeOut(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(getSocketTimeOut(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .followRedirects(true)
                .connectionPool(new ConnectionPool(MAX_TOTAL_CONNECTION, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES))
                .addNetworkInterceptor(new StethoInterceptor())
                .followSslRedirects(true)
                .build();
```

When the connection is set to keep-alive (set by default), some requests fail with the following Java Exceptions :

```
java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: {}HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity

java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: {}HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

These requests always fail with this exception if the request right before it returns a **304 Not Modified** response with an empty body.

Without this 304 response, those requests are processed successfully.

I've read everywhere that the solution is to add the Connection Closed header to requests.

However, I do not want to do that. The Connection Pool we want to use is rendered nearly useless.

Keeping the connection alive is a benefit we had with Apache and we would like to keep the same benefit with OkHttp.

The Server does not seem to be sending a fault response as verified by sending Postman requests to the server which do not fail. Also, our previous Apache client handled these requests correctly.

Adding an interceptor (network or otherwise) does not seem to work. I tried to populate the body or set 'Content-Length' to 0 for the 304 request but the next request always failed.

What are my options?

Comment: Then either the preceding 304 response is malformed, or your library is processing it incorrectly. Do you have a trace?

Answer (score 0):

Your webserver is incorrectly returning response data with an HTTP 304 response. Get ’em to fix that.

While you wait for that, you can workaround with an OkHttp [network interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors) that adds a `Connection: close` header to the response headers for all HTTP 304s.